# Dynamic Dice Roller Spreadsheet using ArrayFormula

Tags: arrays, random, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am making a dice roller tool where the user can adjust both the number of sides on the die and the number of dice rolled.

To do this I have the user indicate the number of sides on the dice in cell B2, and the number of dice to roll in B3.

Then I use

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(E2),SEQUENCE(B3,1,1,1),"-")
```

to create a series of numbers in the E column equal to the number of dice being rolled. Next to this column I use

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D2:D),RANDBETWEEN(1,$B$2),"x")
```

in series to get a selection of random numbers.

This works fine. However, I want to know if someone can show me how they might accomplish the same using an ArrayFormula.

When I try to apply ARRAYFORMULA to the formula I simply get a column of identical numbers.

My task seems like it could be solved using some combination of RANDBETWEEN and RANDARRAY, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do it.

Edit:
Here is a link to the current spreadsheet
[Dice Roller](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-W37KSwDrKjNPvyCP2f56WMUEzXNnYZ2Ob77Ed0PHQ4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Added a link to the spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(SORT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B1)), 
 RANDBETWEEN(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B1))^0, 9^9), 0), 1, 1))
```

[image: 0]

---

**shorter:**

```
=INDEX(SORT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B1)), 
 RANDBETWEEN(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B1))^0, 9^9), ), 1, )
```

or:

```
=INDEX(SORT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B1)), RANDARRAY(B1), ), 1, )
```

Comment: Thank you. That is an interesting approach. I need to learn more about INDIRECT.